# Running server client program in aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a server-client program written in python. It is a simple program using socket programming. It is currently running in my local system. I want this program to run on AWS, so that I can connect my client to the server.

Please help me with how I can deploy my server program to AWS directly.

Comment: I would start with some basic AWS tutorials on how to setup a VM:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/vmlaunch/qs-vmlaunch.pdf

Comment: What have you tried? What problem have you run into? If you just want to have a server in the cloud, you will want to launch an Amazon EC2 instance and install your software.